# como enviar dos datos a un archivo html por medio de socket.io?

Tags: html, angularjs, nodejs

el código con nodejs, estoy trabajando con socket.io

```
function onDato(dato){
io.sockets.emit('lectura', dato);
}
```

aquí muestro el código hecho con angularjs, si me muestra en html el dato pero como estoy mandando dos al mismo tiempo nada mas me muestra uno.

```
    var app = angular.module('tutorial', []);
    var socket = io();

    app.controller('temperatura', ['$scope', function ($scope){

        socket.on('lectura', function(lectura){
         $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.dato = lectura;
             console.log(lectura);
              });
        });

    }]);
```

anexo el código que hice en arduino:

```
#include <DHT.h>
#define DHTPIN 7
#define HT1 7
#define HT2 8
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht1 (HT1, DHTTYPE);
DHT dht2 (HT2, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
dht1.begin();
dht2.begin();


}

void loop() {
float t1, t2;
t1 = dht1.readTemperature();
t2 = dht2.readTemperature();

Serial.println("S1");
Serial.println(t1);
Serial.println("S2");
Serial.println(t2);

delay(10000);
}
```